# PHP function that will turn a time stamp in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss into how old the time stamp is

Tags: php, datetime, date, timestamp

Basically, I have a time stamp that looks like `2010-12-15 16:14:06`. If the time stamp is seconds old I want it transform it into "N Seconds Old." If the time stamp is minutes old, I want it to transform it into "N Minutes Old." etc. Is there any built in PHP functions that will do this?

Comment: Short answer: No. But you can create your own ;)

Comment: Google `PHP relative time` and you will find many scripts for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're running 5.3 you can use [DateTime::diff](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to do it.  It returns a [DateInterval](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object which contains the info you'll want.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you need to have some "starting point" to measure against. There are a number of ways to turn a time stamp such as `2010-12-15 16:14:06` into a PHP timestamp (seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`). If that's your "starting point", simply subtract it from the current time or whatever to get the difference in seconds. If less than a certain amount (say, 60), give that as "N seconds ago". If greater, divide by 60 to get minutes ago, or 3600 to get hours ago, etc.).